# Salesforce integration all-or-nothing

Tags: salesforce

We have a customer who makes use of Salesforce, but they want to develop their own site which will perform a multitude of functions some of which would require integration with Salesforce data and functionality.

In discussions with a Salesforce vendor and our customer, the Salesforce vendor pushed for the customer to do everything in Salesforce itself, as in a portal solution where their entire website is run through Salesforce, or you would switch from some basic HTML pages on your own server to Salesforce pages (Skinned to look like the customer's site).

Surely this recommendation is not in the best interests of the customer?

Doesn't this restrict and limit you to Salesforce technologies and costs?

Long term, if this company decided in the future to expand and build web based functionality that is totally separate from Salesforce what would happen?

Let me know what you think and possibly give me a link or two to motivate what you're saying. 
I'm hoping that system/application architects will be the ones to answer, not Salesforce vendors.

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They may well have been talking about Salesforce Sites. Which do allow you to build a lot of custom functionality, and leverage the power of the Salesforce platform. That said, it does lock you in somewhat. It will likely also limit just what you can do. It really depends just what functionality from Salesforce they want to expose to their customers through the site. It may be a case that a salesforce customer portal (skinned to fit the corporate look and feel) would suffice, and they can leave their existing site alone.

The other option is to build all the functionality on their own site using the SOAP or REST based APIs which Salesforce offer. This has it's pros and cons too. It offers you more flexibility with what you want to do with your site, and you can always switch hosting provider for the site too relatively easily. You could even switch from a PHP to ASP site and still have the same functionality. All of this takes time to develop. It can be used as a way around the expensive salesforce licenses though, and Salesforce just becomes a fancy database for your site in some regards.

Without knowing just how much of the data/functionality within Salesforce the customer wants on their site, And what ultimately they want to get from their website, it is difficult to give a clear answer though.

Comment: thanks for the great answer. My other concern for this company is that they're looking to build up some IP for the company in terms of their web systems,requiring flexibility. Any idea how I can calculate the cost differences between the two routes? I need for this customer to fully understand what they're signing up for. I noticed that Salesforce charges a per user license, or it seemed they had a concurrent active logins type model as well. It seemed that they also charged quite heavily per Gb of data stored (can one safely assume that these costs are reduced by using the rest approach?)

Comment: With Salesforce you do pay per license, and it's not cheap (unless you're an NGO/charity). And there are alot of limits in place. Some of these limits increase the more licenses you have. Eg. the number of API calls you can make is 1000*number of licenses, but with a minimum of 5000 as I recall it. You can use API calls to expose functionality to people and thus circumvent the number of licenses you need. If alot of functionality centres around their web presence then look at building that, and having a scheduled import into Salesforce for CRM/reporting purposes as another option.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check out http://www.magentrix.com, they provide a very flexible and customizable portal for Salesforce.

It's also a cloud-based application, so you are always running the latest version and get tons of new features and tools in each release.

Also the service is offered with a tiered pricing model rather than per user license which makes it more affordable.